# Is "to finance hotel investments" clear?

Tags: phrase-request

I want a title which mean **providing the necessary money for investing in hospitality development**. Does *to finance/financing hotel investments* refer to what I want to say?

Comment: I wouldn't use that phrase, *hotel investments* can mean *investments **for** a hotel/hotels* as well as *investments **made by** a hotel/hotels*. This ambiguity can cause confusion.

Comment: What is this a title for. "To ______" is usually a form of title used for philosophical papers and occasionally books. If this is for an article or presentation, a better form would be with the gerund form - "Financing hotel investments"

Comment: Why not "*Investing in hospitality*"?